# Scrollbar replacement on a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got a row, with X amount of columns inside it. How can I, if there is an overflow of columns, replace the regular scrollbar, with left/right image arrows on each side. See the less than and greater than arrows in the below example to see what I mean.

I want to keep it vanilla JS, not jQuery.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.row {
  width: 90%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.col {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
}

.grey {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  &lt;
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col">
      one
    </div>
    <div class="col grey">
      two
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      three
    </div>
    <div class="col grey">
      four
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      five
    </div>
    <div class="col grey">
      six
    </div>

  </div>
  &gt;
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use jQuery?

Comment: Do you still want to be able to scroll left and right without the scrollbar? Or is it okay just to have the images there? I imagine it's difficult to scroll without a scrollbar and jquery.

Comment: @JosephCho Sorry, im not sure I understand your question. I want it to act kind of like a cariousel, where the browser scrollbar is not visible but you scroll it by clicking a custom image on each side.

Comment: @Manav I prefer vanilla JS.

Comment: I was wondering if you still wanted to be able to scroll (which you do). jQuery was created for these sort of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use jQuery, we can add ID's to the lt and gt symbols. This way we can target the images in an onclick event.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <span id="lt">&lt;</span>
  <div id="row">

    <div class="col">
      one
    </div>
    ...
    <div class="col grey">
      six
    </div>

  </div>
  <span id="gt">&gt;</span>
</div>
```

Then add onclick handlers to the symbols to scroll through the row.

JS:

```
var row = document.getElementById("row");
row.scrollRight = 0;
row.scrollLeft = 0;

document.getElementById("lt").onclick = function(){
    row.scrollLeft = row.scrollLeft - 50;
}

document.getElementById("gt").onclick = function(){
    row.scrollLeft = row.scrollLeft + 50;
}
```

Last, lets remove the horizontal scrollbar.

CSS:

```
#row {
  width: 90%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Working fiddle here: https://fiddle.jshell.net/26jrtdky/1/

Comment: Oops, forgot to save. Updated the link.

Comment: @JosephCho Awesome, thank you, exactly what i needed. And no jquery! Any way to remove the arrows if! there is no overflow?

Comment: Sure... fiddle attached here https://fiddle.jshell.net/26jrtdky/2/. Try playing around with the number of columns and it should adjust. Also, say hello to Claire for me ;)

Comment: @JosephCho again, awesome thanks! Claire says Hello back :D